# How can I do something only if the minibuffer exits normally?

Tags: hooks, minibuffer

Simply attaching to `minibuffer-exit-hook` is not enough, because it also runs when the user presses `C-g`, so the command quits.

Is there a way to determine in the hook if the command is exiting normally?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A minibuffer prompt is a [recursive edit](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Recursive-Editing.html), which ends by either [throwing](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Catch-and-Throw.html) `'exit` or [signaling](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Signaling-Errors.html) [`'quit`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Quitting.html) or another error. I think all normal exits from the minibuffer run [`exit-minibuffer`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Minibuffer-Commands.html#index-exit_002dminibuffer), so you could advise that function.